# How to activate rewrite URL from apache2 with Linux

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently transfered all my websites from Windows to KUbuntu via virtual machine. And now I can't access a part of my website that is using rewrite URL...

I've already activated `rewrite` module with `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and `AllowOverride` in apache2 conf and restarted apache but that still does not work...

At the start, I got 404 errors (without `default.conf` `AllowOverride` things) 
And now I've got a 500 internal error. How don't know how to proceed next, I Googled that problem, but nothing helped me.

**EDIT:** The 500 internal error happened from my `.htaccess`:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

My `default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all 
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                RewriteEngine on
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
# %{HTTP_HOST} = domain
# %{REQUEST_URI} = /vl_web/...


# rewrite pages
RewriteRule ^login$  ./login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^reglement$  ./rules.php [L]
RewriteRule ^changelog$  ./changelog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^government/lspd/$  ./government/panel/?team=LSPD [L]
RewriteRule ^government/bcso/$  ./government/panel/?team=BCSO [L]



# 404 image
# RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp) ./assets/img/misc/404.png [NC,L]
# Ht Errors
ErrorDocument 404 /vl_web/assets/resources/hterr/index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 403 /vl_web/assets/resources/hterr/index.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 500 /vl_web/assets/resources/hterr/index.php?error=500
ErrorDocument 503 /vl_web/assets/resources/hterr/index.php?error=503
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What does your http server's error log file say what is the cause of the http 500?

Comment: Have you enabled mod_headers? _Aside:_ I assume you are using Apache 2.4, in which case you shouldn't be using the `Order`, `Allow` directives...

Comment: Hi, for the apache's error.log, i got two things
 
1. error in my .htaccess 
 `/var/www/html/vl_web/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: 2. php errors (that do not happen on windows so that's pretty weird): 
 `Undefined index: nom in /var/www/html/vl_web/government/panel/files/index/row2.php on line 35, referer: http://192.168.1.29/vl_web/government/`

Comment: 3. 'LimitInternalRecursion' errors:
`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://192.168.1.29/vl_web/`

Comment: OK, so you are quite a step further just by reading the error messages, right?

Comment: Yes I tried to fix the limits but now I can't restart Apache he won't load... That's not a bit weird that I got php errors in Linux but not in Windows ?

Comment: If you can't restart Apache then you probably have a syntax error or invalid character in your config file. Check the _servers_ root error log. Please also add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question, as this is likely the cause of your "internal rewrite loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. error in my `.htaccess` /var/www/html/vl_web/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

`Header` is part of mod_headers, which needs to be _enabled. mod_headers is considered an "Extension", in other words:

> A module with "Extension" status is not normally compiled and loaded into the server. To enable the module and its functionality, you may need to change the server build configuration files and re-compile Apache. (Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/module-dict.html#Status)

Although, this will often just need "enabling" in the server config. (Requiring a webserver restart.)

> 2. php errors (that do not happen on windows so that's pretty weird): Undefined index: nom in `/var/www/html/vl_web/government/panel/files/index/row2.php` on line 35, referer: `http://192.168.1.29/vl_web/government/`

Differences in PHP versions and/or different (default) error_reporting levels could account for the differences in behaviour here. Notably, "Undefined index" messages became an E_WARNING in PHP 7 - previously this was an E_NOTICE.

> 3. 'LimitInternalRecursion' errors: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://192.168.1.29/vl_web/

This is most probably caused by rewrites in your `.htaccess` file.

**Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to you question.**

Of note here is that Windows is a case-insenstive filesystem and Linux is not. The same directive might not match on Linux.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
>     <Directory /var/www/html>
>             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>             AllowOverride all 
>             Order allow,deny
>             allow from all
>             RewriteEngine on
>     </Directory>
> ```

You *probably* want to disable `MultiViews` (you are explicitly enabling it above). If you are doing much with mod_rewrite (in `.htaccess`) then `MultiViews` can often result in conflicts (depends what you are doing).

Do you really want to enable directory `Indexes`?

`Order` and `Allow` are Apache 2.2 directives. You are evidentally on Apache 2.4 so should be using the `Require` directive instead.

You do not need to enable the `RewriteEngine` here unless you are using it in this scope (you are not). If you are using `.htaccess` then this will most probably override this anyway.

In other words, this should probably be written:

```
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All 
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: First thanks a lot for your very detailed answer.
For the `LimitInternalRecursion`error, I fixed it simply by putting it in the `apache2.conf` not in the `sites-available/` folder. Now for the `rewriteUrls` is seems to be good everythings fine! **Thanks a lot!**